# AlertDialog for getting password android

Tags: android, dialog, messagebox

I'm programming in java using Android Studio. I want to `get password` from user using `AlertDialog` and show it using another `AlertDialog`. The problem is that without any prompt for entering password I see second dialog. In other words I always get this message **"your pass is null"**. What is wrong in my codes?

I run dialog codes in a button onClick event:

```
String s = MessageBox.ShowPasswordBox(this, "", "enter password" , "ok" , "cancel");
MessageBox.Show(this, "showing pass", "your pass is " + s , "ok" , "cancel");
```

where  `Show` and `ShowPasswordBox` codes are:

```
public static MessageBoxResult Show(Context context, String title, String message, String positiveMessage, String negativeMessage)
{
    result = MessageBoxResult.Closed;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);

    builder.setPositiveButton(positiveMessage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do nothing but close the dialog
            result = MessageBoxResult.Positive;
            dialog.dismiss();

        }

    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(negativeMessage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            result = MessageBoxResult.Negative;

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

    return result;
}


// return password
public static String ShowPasswordBox(
        Context context, String title, String message, String positiveMessage, String negativeMessage)
{
    stringResult = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);

    // Set up the input
    final EditText input = new EditText(context);

    // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    builder.setView(input);

    // Set up the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton(positiveMessage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            stringResult = input.getText().toString();

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(negativeMessage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


    builder.create().show();

    return stringResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `ShowPasswordBox` method. It returns `stringResult` in whe same moment when first dialog will showed. And than second dialog will showed with not initailized String object. (You can check it if close second dialog you will see first dialog). And `stringResult` will be setted only when user entered field and tap on "ok" button.

1.Try to call just

```
MessageBox.ShowPasswordBox(this, "", "enter password", "ok", "cancel");
```

and modify part of `ShowPasswordBox` method like below.

```
 builder.setPositiveButton(positiveMessage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                stringResult = input.getText().toString();
                MessageBox.Show(context, "showing pass", "your pass is " + stringResult, "ok", "cancel");
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

2.Or if you wanna use `ShowPasswordBox` in general way than you should create own listener and add it in `onClick` method for positive button.

```
public class MessageBox {
    private static PositiveButtonListener listener;
    public static void setListener(PositiveButtonListener newListener) {
        listener = newListener;
    }

    public interface PositiveButtonListener {
        void onPositiveButtonClick(String result);
    }
```

and modify `onClick` method

```
builder.setPositiveButton(positiveMessage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        stringResult = input.getText().toString();
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onPositiveButtonClick(stringResult);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

And call this methods like below.

```
MessageBox.setListener(new MessageBox.PositiveButtonListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPositiveButtonClick(String result) {
        MessageBox.Show(MainActivity.this, "showing pass", "your pass is " + result, "ok", "cancel");
    }
});

MessageBox.ShowPasswordBox(MainActivity.this, "", "enter password", "ok", "cancel");
```

Comment: I don't want to modify `ShowPasseordBox` in such way because I will use it as general method to get other passwords. I want to use it in other part of my code similar to InputBox one from Visual Basic 6.0

Comment: You should understand, android have specific features. So code for android platform and on VisualBasic will be different.